# Easy and common way to separate latent classes from Likert-scale survey?

Tags: likert, latent-variable, latent-class

Let say, there are two 5-points Likert-scale questions "How do you like a flavor?" applied for two product samples. That is, each respondent tries two samples and evaluate them on Likert scale.

Obviously, there are two basic options: one sample is always superior to another; or there are two latent groups: one prefers first one and dislike another; and vice versa.

H0 is "There are no distinct groups. The flavor is one type. Probably just one better than another. Mean measure would be sufficient to understand."

What is the best and possibly common way to demonstrate existing of these groups and strength of this?

Comment: I wouldn't think of this in terms of latent classes. If your response were numeric, I would treat this as a clustering question. Is the bivariate distribution of the ratings bi-modal or unimodal? Your data is ordinal, which is intriguing. Likerts are often treated as numerics without too many problems. The effect size here will be the distance (possibly scaled) between centroids of the 2 clusters your find.

Comment: Thank you for response! I checked my data (numeric, 1-5) and in last particular case both samples got equally highest scores. However, I run this test quite often with different results and willing to establish universal model. Your clustering method looks very promessing. Could you advice, how I can find centroids and cluster sizes??

Comment: I think the following simple algorithm: just subtract each response for sample A from B and calculate total amount of zeros, positive and negative results. Closer to 50/50 ratio for negatives/positives will lead to more distinct clusters. What do you think?

Comment: That would lead you to a non-parametric test for the equality of the two flavours -- it's called the sign test. But I thought you wanted to see if you had two sorts of people in the population: those with a marked preference for vanilla (say) and those with a marked preference for chocolate. In fact, there could be other groups -- those who hate both flavours and those who like both flavours. A K-means clustering algorithm will assign clusters, and then you can assess -- either graphically or using something like the Calinski-harabasz index to choose the number of clusters.

Comment: Placidia, thank you so much for advice. I investigated K-means algorithm and it works. However I still struggling with application. Let say, I consider two columns - Sample A and Sample B flavors for 100 respondents. K-means algorithm found two cluster with certain means across all 200 responses. But it's not that I wanted to accomplish. I have to find if there are some groups that evaluated A and B differently (or similarly). That is essential what I should find out. I can't catch how means can help me. Perhaps, I should apply K-means to difference between A and B?

Comment: See my response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test whether the data are consistent with two distinct groups of "aggree" on both flavours" or "strongly disagree", then you need to model that situation. You could take $|A-B|$, as the absolute value of the difference. You have now transformed your two dimensional data into one dimension, but it's the dimension that pinpoints the difference you care about. At this point, I would plot a histogram of the data with density function overlayed and gawk at it. If the effect is pronounced (there really are two groups), you should see two good peaks -- one at 0 and one positive, with a trough between them. If there's nothing to see, it's doubtful that a statistical test will reveal anything.

If you do need a test, I think you need to go back to first principles and design something. If you assume your original responses are normal, then |A-B| is a [folded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) normal. You want to fit a mixture of folded normals where one comes from a mean 0 distribution. The other has a mean to be determined. You could presumably write down a likelihood for this and compare to the likelihood obtained from one folded normal. You would have to set up the optimization yourself and it would involve an iterative process. When fitting the mixture distribution, you have to estimate which group each observation belongs to. The usual standard methods probably don't apply to your specific research question.

Comment: Thank you! My thoughts were almost the same. So far I came up to Spearman's. Actually, it looks like I can't conclude if I have two distinct groups of products ("vanilla" of "chocolate") if my respondents like or dislike them in the same way. The only situation if I can make them out if they like vanilla but dislike chocolate. In this situation, Spearman's should make good job (be negative), right? I tried to apply this approach to the quite a number of actual results and always got very high r (0,6-0,9).  We have just two versions of vanilla - better and worse, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You could do a Spearman's, certainly. It wouldn't answer the question of whether there are two groups of people.

Comment: As you initially and correctly mentioned, there are potentially 4 groups (for 2 products): "like both", "hate both", "like first, hate second", "like second, hate first". Even if first two groups exist, we can't conclude if there are really two different type of products (vanilla, chocolate) because they equally can hate (or like) products independently of their nature. It could be "bad vanilla" and "good vanilla" but could be "bad vanilla" and "good chocolate". There is no enough information to distinct these two groups. The only we can do - to distinct contrast preferences.